# Is it possible to select only repeated values from a single column using eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Table

```
id|p.id|product

1 |8   |chair
2 |8   |table
3 |2   |chair
4 |4   |guitar
5 |8   |glasses
```

I would like to select p.id 8 and p.id 2 products however I I want the repeated values (chair). This is the opposite of distinct. So far I have

```
$product =modelname::whereIn('p.id', array(8,2))->select('product')->get();
```

This obviously selects the 2 p.id's however I'm unaware of how to use aggregate functions such as count when using eloquent. Any help is much appreciated. (I use laravel 4.2 btw)

Comment: What is the exact result you want to get for above data?

Comment: The exact result is chair. I only want the product and not the values that are distinct (repeated values only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename your `p.id` into `p_id` using:

```
$product= modelname::selectRaw('product, count(product) AS aggregate')->whereIn('p_id', array(8,2))->groupBy('product')->having('aggregate','>',1)->get();
```

you will get as result:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#121 ▼
    +"product": "chair"
    +"aggregate": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select value of p.id 8 and p.id 2 you can use the code like

```
$product = Modelname::whereIn('p.id', array(8,2))->get();
```

Now the `$product` variable contact the value in array format. now you can pass the variable to view or if you want the count use `count($product)`